# Accuracy on training data in Gradient boosting classifier- scikit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gradient-descent, boosting

I am training GBC. It is multi class classifier with 12 classes of outputs. My issue is I am not getting 100% accuracy when i predict on the train data. In fact, misprediction happens on dominant set of classes. (my input is imbanalanced and i do synthetic data creation.)

Here are details:
Input data size:
Input shape:  (20744, 13) 
(doing label encoding and minmax scaling on output and input)

Distribution before scaling of data:

```
[(0, 443), **(1, 6878),** (2, 177), (3, 1255), (4, 311), (5, 172), (6, 1029), (7, 268), (8, 131), (9, 54), (10, 1159), (11, 340), (12, 1370),
**(13, 7157)**]
```

Oversampling with random oversampler

```
[(0, 7157), (1, 7157), (2, 7157), (3, 7157), (4, 7157), (5, 7157), (6, 7157), (7, 7157), (8, 7157), (9, 7157), (10, 7157), (11, 7157), (12, 7157), (13, 7157)]
```

final shapes after preprocessing:
Input shape X:  (100198, 12)
Target Shape Y:  (100198, 1)

Model:
est = GradientBoostingClassifier(verbose=3, n_estimators=n_est, learning_rate=0.001, max_depth =24, min_samples_leaf=3, max_features=3)

outputs:

```
ACC: 0.9632                                                     
Feature importance:                                             
[0.09169515 0.01167983 0.         0.         0.11126567 0.14089752
 0.12381927 0.10735138 0.1344401  0.13874134 0.08111774 0.058992  ]
Accuracy score on Test data:  19303                                
[[1406    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [  19 1024    4   32    4    5   24    5    0    0   24    8   48  211]
 [   0    0 1434    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   1    8    0 1423    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0 1441    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0 1430    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0 1439    0    0    0    3    0    0    1]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 1453    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 1432    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 1445    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 1398    0    0    1]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 1411    0    0]
 [   0    5    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 1413    6]
 [   1  154    9   22   12    6   22    6    3    8   17   20   45 1154]]
```

Precision on Test data:  0.9632235528942116

### Recall on Test data:  0.9632235528942116

**The problem I see is when i predict on train data: I expect a 100% prediction. But somehow my dominant classes are not 100% predicted. Any reason?

```
ACC: 0.9982**
Accuracy score on Train data:  80016
[[5751    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   **0 5699    2    2    1    0    1    3    3    2    0    2    2   32**]
 [   0    0 5723    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0 5725    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0 5716    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0 5727    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0 5714    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 5704    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 5725    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 5712    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 5756    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 5746    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1 5731    0]
 [   **0    4    5    5    5    2    9    8    2   16    6   19   10 5587**]]
```

Precision on Train data:  0.9982284987150378
Recall on Train data:  0.9982284987150378

Any idea as what's going wrong?

Comment: How are you making the train and test set? After oversampling or before?

Comment: After, 80-20 split.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should NOT apply `minmax()` standardisation, or any standardisation for that matter, on multi-class **label** column. Apply standardisation on features matrix only. In a classification problem, the label has to be treated as discrete, categorical entity (even encoding the label classes into ordinal numbers is optional, at least in `sklearn`).

Secondly, why do you expect 100% classification accuracy for training set? Are you implying accuracy with training set should always be 100% or there is something special about your model which makes you expect 100% accuracy? A well-generalised good model is where difference between training and test accuracy is very small, if any. Of course, *ideally*, both train and test classification should be close to 100% but that is extremely rare. A 100% accuracy with *only* train set is not a measure of a good model.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I apply minmaxscaler() only on input feature set. 
I do only label encoding on target column.

I am wondering whether this points to any issue with the model? How do i know if it is highly biased or highly varianced model etc.

Comment: Earlier version of your question said you applied minmax() scaling on label, too. Anyways, high variance ==> over-fit ==> higher training accuracy than test accuracy. Always compute both training accuracy and test accuracy and if training accuracy is much higher, there me be high variance in your model. Conversely, high bias ==> under-fit model.